# JS bitwise shift operator '>>' not returning the correct result

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I found this weird problem in JS. I have some native bindings to a board game api that uses bitboards for representing the game state.
I am trying to manipulate these bitboards in JS to display the result in a web-based GUI (using electron).

The `1`s in the bitboard represent the position of the pieces. Here is an example:

```js
const bitboard = 0b100000010000000000000000000000000000;
```

However, when I do `bitboard >>= 1;`, the value magically becomes `0b1000000000000000000000000000`.

Runnable example:

```js
const bitboard = 0b100000010000000000000000000000000000; // 0b is binary literal
console.log(bitboard.toString(2));
console.log((bitboard >> 1).toString(2)); // .toString(2) prints the number in binary
```

Edit:
The same code works in Rust which is the language that I am using on the native side.

Comment: JavaScript's "numbers" are all floating-point internally so you can get a lot of weirdness with values like this that are > ~2^28. You may want `>>>` instead which is the "zero-fill right-shift operator".

Comment: Tip: Just delete the last character of a string representation.

Comment: bitwise operators work with 32bit values - you have 36bits

Comment: @JaromandaX With testing I found the break-point to be 29 bits, so that approximation is close. This is specifically for bit-shifting, not general-purpose numbers.

Comment: @JaromandaX Misread the number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's probably a duplicate floating around somewhere but the solution here is to use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

> **`BigInt`** is a built-in object that provides a way to represent whole numbers larger than 2<sup>53</sup> - 1, which is the largest number JavaScript can reliably represent with the `Number` primitive and represented by the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant. `BigInt` can be used for arbitrarily large integers.

You just need to make sure that both operands for the right-shift operator are the same type.

```js
const bitboard = BigInt("0b100000010000000000000000000000000000")
console.log(bitboard.toString(2))
console.log((bitboard >> 1n).toString(2)) // note "1n"
```

Comment: Thanks! It's kind of weird that JS doesn't have separate types for ints and floats.

Comment: @LuketheGeek - well ... it was written in 11 days :p

Comment: This solved something  that was troubling me for a day, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are limits on what sorts of numerical values JavaScript can bit-shift. Using Node I found the cut-off right here at 32 bits:

```
0b10000000000000000000000000000000 >>> 1 // 32 bits
# => 1073741824
0b100000000000000000000000000000000 >>> 1 // 33 bits
# => 0
```

Where it just breaks down. Your binary value is over that threshold so you can't shift it using JavaScript's default representation.

You can do this with [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
BigInt('0b100000010000000000000000000000000000') >> BigInt(1)
# => 17314086912n
```

Where that is the correct value.

Comment: `I found the cut-off right here` - at 32 bits .... not 28/29 like you say in your comments

Comment: @JaromandaX I guess I'm bad at counting. In any case, that's the break-point.